# Can you create a Restriction for a Detached Criteria on a primitive collection?

Tags: nhibernate, primitive, detachedcriteria, restrictions

I would like to know if there is a way to create a Restriction on a primitive collection of a Model in NHibernate.3.3.3?

Here's the details:

```
class Parent { 
    IEnumerable<string> ChildNames { get; set; }

}
```

I need to search like so:

```
private DetachedCriteria BuildQuery() {
    var inNames = { "Bob", "Sam", "Dan" };
    var query = DetachedCriteria.For<Parent>("parent");
    query.Add(Restrictions.In("ChildNames", inNames));
    return query;
}
```

I found this old question that says it's not possible, but given the fact that it's old and doesn't have a ton of upvotes, I'd like to confirm before I refactor.

If I can do it and I'm totally botching it, I'll take that help as well!

Comment: Check
[this][1], using your in clause restriction.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209373/nhibernate-how-do-i-query-against-an-iliststring-property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up, like many, refactoring the collection into a strong type.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, we can use `Projection` *(something less type-safe, then mapped Property, but more flexible)*.

Let's expect the mapping like this:

```
<bag name="ChildNames" inverse="false" lazy="true" table="[dbo].[ChildNames]" 
    cascade="all"
    batch-size="25">
  <key column="ParentId" />
  <element type="System.String" column="ChildName" />
</bag>
```

Then we can adjust the Build query method like this:

```
protected virtual DetachedCriteria BuildQuery()
{
    var inNames = new [] { "Bob", "Sam", "Dan" };

    // parent query reference
    var query = DetachedCriteria.For<Parent>("parent");
    // reference to child query
    var child = query.CreateCriteria("ChildNames");

    // let's project the column name of the Element, e.g. 'Name'
    var columnNameProjection = Projections.SqlProjection(
        "ChildName as name", null, new IType[] { NHibernateUtil.String }
        );

    // in clause
    child.Add(Restrictions.In(
        columnNameProjection, inNames
        ));

    return query;
}
```

And this is what we will get:

```
SELECT ...
 FROM Parent this_ 
  inner join [dbo].[ChildNames] childNames3_ 
    on this_.ParentId=childNames3_.ParentId 
 WHERE ChildName in (@p0, @p1, @p2)
 ...
 @p0=N'Bob',@p1=N'Sam',@p2=N'Dan'
```

The caveat:

*While this is in deed working... the `ChildName` is used without the Alias. That could be pretty tricky to fulfill... so be careful, if there are more columns with the name `ChildName` in this scenario*