# CreateCriteria over a collection of simple types

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

How can I query using `CreateCriteria` over a collection of simple types?

For example, I have 1 class

```
public class Test
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    private ICollection<int> _values = new HashedSet<int>();        
    public virtual ICollection<int> Values
    {
        get { return _values; }
    }
}
```

And 2 tables to support it:

- Test with only 1 column: Id
- Values with 2 columns: TestId and Value

**My goal is to rewrite the following query using `CreateCriteria`**:

```
select * from test t
inner join values v on v.TestId = t.Id
where v.Value = 10
```

I have tried this:

```
Session.CreateCriteria<Test>("test")
  .CreateAlias("test.Values", "values")
  .Add(Restrictions.Eq("values", 10))
  .List();
```

Like I would done it with a collection of objects and, obviously, failed. The join is correct but how to add a restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite of the question, I would suggest to use `IList<ValueEntity>` rather then `IList<int>`.

Well, that would be working only if the table containing the values *([dbo].[values])* could have its own surrogated ID column. I.e. with these columns: `ID`, `TestId`, `Value` we could introduce new entity *ValueEntity* and map it as first level citizens. Querying it then would become much more simple, including subqueries..

But I know that this is not a question here.

And in fact, there is a solution, there is answer to the above question. But please, at least try to consider the above suggestion...

NHibernate solution for `IList<int>` collection querying is:

```
Session.CreateCriteria<Test>("test")
  .CreateAlias("test.Values", "values")
  // we add magic keyword ".elements" here
  .Add(Restrictions.Eq("values.elements", 10))
  .List();
```

See the ".elements" which is a bit inproperly documented [here](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-aliasreferences). Also provided an answer to this similar quetion: [NHibernate How do I query against an IList<string> property?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1209373/1679310)

Answer (score 0):

The approach with `elements` didnt worked for me. Somehow NHibernate picked the wrong aliases...
So from

```
CurrentSession.CreateCriteria<EmployeeIntranetSettings>("settings")
    .CreateAlias("settings.DefaultLMSOwnershipCapacities", "capacity")
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("capacity.elements", OwnershipCapacity.VehicleFinance))
    .SetProjection(Projections.Id())
    .List<Guid>();
```

It created

```
SELECT this_.Id as y0_ 
FROM intranet.sfEmployeeIntranetSettings this_ 
inner join contact.sfEmployeeDefaultLMSOwnershipCapacities defaultlms3_ on this_.Id=defaultlms3_.EmployeeId
WHERE capacity1_.Capacity = @p0
```

As you can see - aliases for capacities are different.

So I would second the suggestion about the ValueType Entity despite the fact that it might be against DDD. And as a working solution with a current architecture (at least for me):

```
CurrentSession.CreateCriteria<Employee>("employee")
    .Add(Expression.Sql(
        "Exists (select top 1 null from contact.sfEmployeeDefaultLMSOwnershipCapacities dc where dc.EmployeeId = {alias}.Id and dc.Capacity = ?)", 
        "'" + OwnershipCapacity.VehicleFinance + "'", 
        NHibernateUtil.String))
    .SetProjection(Projections.Id())
    .List<Guid>();
```

Few point of interest here:

- `{alias}` will lead to the root entity alias (employee) in my case. Unfortunately, you cannot use any other aliases;
- for sql query I have used `value` - it will replace `?`, but as it is a string - I had to escape it with `"'"`.