# NHibernate: Select item with entry in element bag

Tags: c#, nhibernate, criteria-api, queryover

I have a class with property of list.

```
public class Paperboy{
     private int _id;
     private string _lastname;
     private string _firstname;
     private string _mobile;
     private string _phone;

     private IList<string> _additionalPhoneNumbers;
}
```

The List is mapped as bag with key and element.

```
<class name="Paperboy" table="tblPaperboy" lazy="false">
 <id name="_id" column="Id" access="field" >
  <generator class="assigned"/>
 </id>
 <property name ="_lastname" column="Lastname" access ="field" />
 <property name ="_firstname" column="Firstname" access ="field" />
 <property name ="_phone" column="Phone" access ="field" />
 <property name ="_mobile" column="Mobile" access ="field" />

 <bag name="_additionalPhoneNumbers" access="field" fetch="subselect" lazy="false" table="tblPaperboyAdditionalPhoneNumbers">
  <key column="PaperboyId"/>
  <element column="PhoneNumber" type="string"/>     
 </bag>
</class>
```

Now I try to select paberboys by their phone number (_phone, _mobile or in _additionalPhoneNumbers). _phone and _mobile are no problem but I am stuck with the additional numbers.

I tried with criteria api and with query over.

Criteria Api does not know the property AdditionalPhoneNumbers

```
ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Paperboy));
criteria.CreateAlias("_additionalPhoneNumbers", "AdditionalPhoneNumbers");

Disjunction or = Restrictions.Disjunction();
or.Add(Restrictions.Eq("_phone", number));
or.Add(Restrictions.Eq("_mobile", number));
or.Add(Restrictions.Eq("AdditionalPhoneNumbers", number));

criteria.Add(or);
criteria.SetMaxResults(1);
return criteria.UniqueResult<Paperboy>();
```

Query Over does not know Contains:

```
 return query.Where(p => p.Mobile == number || p.Phone == number p.AdditionalPhoneNumbers.Contains(number)).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
```

Could someone help me out?

---

UPDATE:

I was pointed to the elements-keyword. After implementing I get an SQL-Exception.

```
 ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Paperboy));
 criteria.CreateAlias("_additionalPhoneNumbers", "APN");

 Disjunction or = Restrictions.Disjunction();
 or.Add(Restrictions.Eq("APN.elements", number));

 criteria.Add(or);
 criteria.SetMaxResults(1);
 return criteria.UniqueResult<Paperboy>();
```

Exception like this.

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Der mehrteilige Bezeichner 'apn1_.PhoneNumber' konnte nicht gebunden werden.`

Problem is the alias for join is not used in the where clause for the property.
apn1_ (where) vs. additiona4_ (join).

Produced SQL:

`[SELECT TOP (@p0)  this_.Id as Id3_1_, this_.BusinessId as BusinessId3_1_, this_.AgencyKey as AgencyKey3_1_, this_.Lastname as Lastname3_1_, this_.Firstname as Firstname3_1_, this_.Title as Title3_1_, this_.Street as Street3_1_, this_.Zip as Zip3_1_, this_.City as City3_1_, this_.Phone as Phone3_1_, this_.Mobile as Mobile3_1_, this_.Comment as Comment3_1_, this_.StaffId as StaffId3_1_, this_.IsActive as IsActive3_1_, agency3_.Id as Id1_0_, agency3_.BusinessId as BusinessId1_0_, agency3_.RegionKey as RegionKey1_0_, agency3_.Shorttext as Shorttext1_0_, agency3_.Longtext as Longtext1_0_, agency3_.CompanyCodeId as CompanyC6_1_0_ FROM tblPaperboy this_ left outer join tblAgency agency3_ on this_.AgencyKey=agency3_.Id inner join tblPaperboyAdditionalPhoneNumbers additiona4_ on this_.Id=additiona4_.PaperboyId WHERE (apn1_.PhoneNumber = @p1)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost the same answer I just gave to previous NHibernate question: [QueryOver IList<string> property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27954519/1679310)

Based on this Q & A: [NHibernate How do I query against an IList property?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26755815/1679310)

Where I tried to show that *(as mentioned in the documentation)* we can use magical word **`".elements"`**:

#### [17.1.4.1. Alias and property references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26755815/1679310)

So the query which will touch the string elements in your case

```
//or.Add(Restrictions.Eq("AdditionalPhoneNumbers", number));
or.Add(Restrictions.Eq("AdditionalPhoneNumbers.elements", number));
```

And that will support filtering `IList<string>`

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I get an SQL-Error, because the join alias (... inner join tblPaperboyAdditionalPhoneNumbers additiona4_ on ...) does not match the used property prefix (additional1_.PhoneNumber). Is it a bug in NHibernate? In the sample some many-to-ones are left out in the mapping.

Comment: That is weird, because if you used alias `criteria.CreateAlias("_additionalPhoneNumbers", "AdditionalPhoneNumbers");` it should now be working with restriction `(Restrictions.Eq("AdditionalPhoneNumbers.elements", number)`. I did test that locally. Could you show me your latest code? and add the exception full stack trace? I am sure we will make it.

Comment: Added current code to the post. As I said, the original Paperboy-class has another property mapped as many-to-one.

Comment: will check give me few mintues

Comment: I am using NHibernate 4.0.2 and I followed your model and that is my query by NHibernate `exec sp_executesql N'SELECT this_.Id as Paperboy1_39_1_ FROM tblPaperboy this_ inner join tblPaperboyAdditionalPhoneNumbers apn1_ on this_.PaperboyId=apn1_.PaperboyId WHERE (apn1_.PhoneNumber = @p0) ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST @p1 ROWS ONLY',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 int',@p0=N'abc',@p1=1` is this working wheny ou try to execute that - **because for me it is working**

Comment: I am (shockingly) using NHibernate 3.0. I will update to 3.2 and check if it still doesnt work. By the way, I added the produced sql to the post. Exception is still the same.

Comment: We do have a progress ;) and soon we will have solution ;) BTW, important note - I migrated from 3 to 4.0 without any issues. Maybe - you should do the same. Really

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68882/discussion-between-tobias-and-radim-kohler).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like NHibernate < 4 has a bug with creating the join.
With the help of [Radim Köhler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679310/radim-k%C3%B6hler) and [firo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/671619/firo) ([see other Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27979402/hql-replace-on-elements)) I ended up using HQL:

```
select
   paperboy
from
   Paperboy as paperboy 
left join 
   paperboy._additionalPhoneNumbers number
where
   paperboy._mobile = :nr or
   paperboy._phone = :nr or
   number = :nr
```

It is also possible to avoid the join by using `:nr in elements(paperboy._additionalPhoneNumbers)` but than I could not replace some characters in the additional number.

Comment: Great job Tobias, nice to see that you make it

Comment: Thanks and Greetings from Dresden to my favorit city Prague.