# nhibernate query using criteria for list of value type

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Class contains List of int: `ICollection<int> CategoryEnum`

How I can create a query criteria for that?

I tried:

```
List<int> postedCategories = new List<int>{ 1 };
int category = 0;

q.JoinAlias(p => p.CategoryEnum, () => category)
 .AndRestrictionOn(x => category)
   .IsIn(postedCategories);
```

but I get a sql query 
WHERE  0  in (1)

I don't have a problem for collecion of object, it works but it doesn't work for collection of int.

This is part of my mapping:

```
<set name="CategoryEnum" table="CategoriesEnum">
  <key column="Id"></key>
  <element column="CategoryId" type="int"></element>
</set>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these Q & A:

- [NHibernate: Select item with entry in element bag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27962300/1679310).
- [NHibernate How do I query against an `IList<string>` property?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26755815/1679310)

You will find, that we can access element with a keyword **`".elements"`**

```
Restrictions.In("category.elements", postedCategories)
```

with query over:

```
q.JoinAlias(p => p.CategoryEnum, () => category)
 .Where(Restrictions.In("category.elements", postedCategories))
```