# How can I query a list of key value pairs using NHibernate ICriteria?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria, icriteria

I have a class with a number of fields, one being an `IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.

```
public class Foo
{
  public IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using Fluent NHibernate and that particular field is mapped as follows:

```
HasMany(x => x.Bars).Component(Bar.Map);
```

and

```
public class BarMap : ComponentMap<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
        public BarMap()
        {
            Map(x => x.Key);
            Map(x => x.Value);
        }

        public static void Map(CompositeElementPart<KeyValuePair<string, string>> part)
        {
            part.Map(x => x.Key);
            part.Map(x => x.Value);
        }
    }
```

Using the ICriteria API, I would like to be able to select all Foo where Bars contains a key value pair `{ X, Y }`, and for the matching of X and Y values to be case insensitive. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way how to query IDictionary is in detail described here

- [NHibernate: Select item with entry in element bag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27961444/1679310) or
- [NHibernate How do I query against an IList property?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26755815/1679310)

and documented here

#### [17.1.4.1. Alias and property references](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querysql.html#querysql-aliasreferences)

```
Description                     Syntax                Example
A collection key                {[aliasname].key}     ORGID as {coll.key}
The id of an collection         {[aliasname].id}      EMPID as {coll.id}
The element of an collection    {[aliasname].element} XID as {coll.element}
```

So, we can do something like this

```
.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Bars.elements", searchedValue));
```