# NHibernate QueryOver where value is IN list property/field?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I have a very basic model:

```
public class Blog : UniqueEntity<Guid>
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Tagline { get; set; }
    public virtual string ActiveThemeName { get; set; }
    public virtual string MainDomain { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<string> DomainAliases { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

I need to write an NHibernate `QueryOver` query `WHERE "hostname string" IN DomainAliases`.

I've found a lot of answers here on SO on how I would do this in the reverse direction, ie: `WHERE DomainAliases CONTAINS "hostname string" but none for what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution, as described here:

[NHibernate: Select item with entry in element bag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27961444/1679310)

should be like this:

```
var demos = this.session.CreateCriteria<Blog>()
    .CreateAlias("DomainAliases", "d")

    // .elemnts is what we need
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("d.elements", "hostname string"))

    .List<Blog>();
```

Also check the:

#### [NHibernate How do I query against an IList property?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26755815/1679310)

Comment: It's not a QueryOver query but it does work. I try and stay away from the criteria API though, too many magic strings and chances for typos for my liking.